# scala generic instance, cannot reference variable within the generic type

Tags: scala, generics, compilation

Stuck on this problem. Can use a workaround, but hate to lose the type-safety. Sample code:

```
package test
trait RecDefClass

trait RecDefObj {
  def runTest = doInstance(Test())
  def doInstance[T <: RecDefClass](instance:T)
}

case class Test(id:Long = 1, name:String = "Name of Test") extends RecDefClass

object Test extends RecDefObj {
  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = {
    runTest
  }
  def doInstance[Test](instance:Test) = {
    println("Class of 'instance'    -- " + instance.getClass.getName)
    println("Class of object Test   -- " + this.getClass.getName)
    println("toString of 'instance' -- " + instance.toString)
    val fixed = instance.asInstanceOf[Test]
    // instance.id
    // fixed.id
  }
}
```

The code on line 21 -- instance.id -- generates a compile error. Even line 22 -- fixed.id -- generates a compile error (even though 'fixed' was coerced to be of type Test).

With these lines commented out, the code executes and produces this:

```
Class of 'instance'    -- test.Test
Class of object Test   -- test.Test$
toString of 'instance' -- Test(1,Name of Test)
```

exactly as expected.

Any thoughts, suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You probably want to move the generic to the class level.

Answer (score 3):

`def doInstance[T <: RecDefClass](instance:T)` vs `doInstance[Test](instance:Test)`. You widened the generic (as if you did `def doInstance[Test <: Any](instance:Test)`). You did NOT applied `Test` as type parameter on definition (it's not C++ template specialization).

Original accepted `T <: RecDefClass`, the implementation uses type parameter `Test` - which means that it no longer expects it to be `<: RecDefClass`, it can be whatever type you pass inside, just that this time you named it `Test`.

This `[Test]` type parameter overshadows type `Test` from above, meaning that this `Test` is NOT the `case case` but some `T <: Any`. That's why the compiler complains.

In other words:

When you are *defining* `def something[Test](...)` you are creating a NEW type `Test` seen only inside `something`. This `Test` would overshade other types having the same name.

When you are *calling* `something[Test]` you are telling compiler that object coming in will use `Test` type (as known outside) in place of whatever type parameter was called both in arguments and in returned value.

Your code is thus equal to

```
object Test extends RecDefObj {
  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = {
    runTest
  }
  def doInstance[T <: Any](instance:T) = {
    println("Class of 'instance'    -- " + instance.getClass.getName)
    // instance doesn't have to be of instance `Test`
    // so the code below is lying
    println("Class of object Test   -- " + this.getClass.getName)
    println("toString of 'instance' -- " + instance.toString)
    // [Test] inside overshaded case class Test outside
    // so this is what you actually got
    val fixed = instance.asInstanceOf[T]
    // instance.id
    // fixed.id
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I'm still confused. In the first line of your response the 'this' vs 'that' shows the same thing? And isn't then substituting doInstance[Test](....) the reason to use the [T <: RecDefClass]?

Comment: I copied the wrong definition, my bad. See now.